# select employees from table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

hello guys   i have following question related to   following problem

```
From tables emp and dept find number of employees working in every departments by their jobs.
Showing number not more than 5.
```

i wrote  following thing

```
select count(*)
from emp  e,dept d
where  e.department_id=d.department_id  and  count(*)<5

group by   e.department_id,e.job;
```

but it shows me  following errors

```
Error at Command Line:3 Column:23
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

what is problem?please help me

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: thanks for  error  hinting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    emp  e 
        INNER JOIN dept d 
            ON e.department_id=d.department_id  
GROUP   BY   e.department_id,e.job
HAVING  count(*)<5 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to filter based on the `count(*)` value, you need to use a `HAVING` clause. A `HAVING` clause uses an aggregate function for filtering.

While there is nothing wrong with [@JW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689194/select-employees-from-table-in-oracle/14689211#14689211), I would change it slightly to use ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of the `JOIN` syntax in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select count(*) Total
from emp e
inner join dept d
    on e.department_id=d.department_id  
group by e.department_id, e.job 
having count(*) < 5
```

Or you can make your query a subquery to filter using the `WHERE`:

```
select Total
from
(
   select count(*) Total
   from emp e
   inner join dept d
      on e.department_id=d.department_id  
   group by e.department_id, e.job 
) src
where total < 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:: `having`

```
select count(*)
from emp  e,dept d
where  e.department_id=d.department_id  

group by   e.department_id,e.job having count(*)<5;
```